# Repetitions as an Hylomorphism

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes, catamorphism, anamorphism

So I've been trying to convert this Haskell function thats checks if a list doesn't have any repetitions into an Hylomorphism, but there's something odd about it.

```
valid :: [a] -> Bool
valid [] = True
valid (h:t) = if (not (elem h t)) then valid t else False
```

I'll be glad if anyone can help! Thx

Comment: What is odd about that?

Comment: My idea was to check if the head is in the tail, like aux(a,t) => checks if a appears in t, but when i try to do it, apparently I'm building a list of Bools

Comment: You are mistaken, the function does what you said it should.

Answer (score 3):

Well a *hylomoprhism* is a function *h : A → C* that can be defined in an anamoprhism (*g* and *p*) and catamorphism (*c* and *⊕*) part.

The anamorphism part consists of a function *g : A → B × A* that "unfolds" the object into smaller parts, and *p : A → Bool* a predicate that determines if we are done unfolding.

The *catamorphism* part consists of a value *c ∈ C* and an operator *⊕ : B × C → C*.

(this text is a slightly modified version of the [*Wikipedia page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylomorphism_(computer_science)#Formal_definition))

In your case the *unfolding* means that we unfold a list in some value (of type *B*, and a *recursive* part, that is here the *tail* of the list.

The predicate *p* can be derived out of your definition: if the list is empty, then we have terminated. It is clear that in that case we return `True`, so that means *c* is `True`.

So now what would the *B* part be? Well if we look at your function we need access to both the *head* and the *tail* of the list, so *B* can be seen as a 2-tuple containing the head (as first element), and a tail (as second element).

So now the remaining question is what *⊕* does? It takes as input a 2-tuple of type *E×[E]* (pseudo-Haskell notation), and a boolean (type *C* which is a `Bool`). As we can see, it checks if the head is en element of the tail. If that is the case, it returns `False`, and ignores the recursive part, otherwise it returns the recursive part.

So we can write this in Haskell like:

```
-- types
type A e = [e]
type B e = (e, [e])
type C = Bool

-- functions
p :: A e -> Bool
p [] = True
p (_:_) = False

g :: A e -> (B e, A e)
g (h:t) = ((h, t), t)

c :: C
c = True

plus :: Eq e => B e -> C -> C
plus (h, t) r | elem h t = False
              | otherwise = r

hylo :: Eq e => A e -> C
hylo a | p a = c
       | otherwise = plus b (hylo a')
    where (b, a') = g a
```

`hylo` is thus a straighforward implementation based on the definition where we thus take the functions `p`, `c`, `plus` and `g` as "building blocks".